# Chrome - Authentication Required. The server requires a username and password

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

We have a web application that has been working for a long time.  A couple days ago, users started to report that after changing their domain password, Chrome started to show a popup stating:  "Authentication required.  The server server123 requires a username and password".

Some information:

1. this only appears for Chrome.  The "authentication required" popup box 
   does not appear with Internet Explorer or Firefox.
2. The website is only exposed internally to our company, not to the 
   outside world
3. We do not have a DNS entry for the website, so users simply access it 
   via the web-server name and application:  http://server123/website
4. This was reported by a user only after they updated their domain password
5. I am unable to duplicate the issue using Chrome from my computer using 
   the same address
6. I found the following:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic
   /chrome/vA7oWrxIE8k and followed the steps listed by pbellrichard on 
   2/12/2010 and this did not correct the issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related and seems to be a Chrome specific issue that can better be addressed by Google assuming the fault is not in your local network/domain setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having this problem that Chrome recently created:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544255

I'm not savvy enough to understand what the problem is but it looks like they're going to be trying to merge a fix back into v47.

Also from the comments it doesn't look to have a permanent workaround.

Cheers!

(Update)
Looks like it was resolved as of v47.0.2526.80 (see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544255#c205)

Answer (score 0):

The request for username and password stems from the Zenmate Chrome Extension VPN on server **pingcdn.org** or similar, depending on locality.